# How to print the last lines from several files?

Tags: awk, tail

I tried:

```
awk 'FRN==NR {print FILENAME, $0} {nextfile}' *.asc > end
awk 'END {print FILENAME, $0} {nextfile}' *.asc > end1
df --total | tail -1 | awk '{print FILENAME, $0}' *asc > end2
```

The first command creates an empty file, the second is too long - there are not only the last lines and the third print only one line. Thank you

Example:

file1.asc

```
1
2
3
```

file2.asc

```
7
45
6
```

desired result:

```
3
6
```

Comment: `FRN` != `FNR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize the ENDFILE rule if you have GAWK.

```
awk 'ENDFILE{print FILENAME, $0}' *.asc
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest `tail`:

```
tail -q -n 1 *.asc
```